# How do we show a custom error message under a text field in an alert?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Can anyone advise as I have an email field in an alert with submit and cancel buttons.

I have a `Bool` function which returns the email validation result which I'm using in `UIAlertAction` and showing a custom message with `NSLog` statement.

My question is when user presses submit button and if `bool` value is zero, I want to show the entered email text in the `UITextField` along with an error message in red at the bottom of the text field. Also alert should be visible until the `bool` value is returned as 1.

**Code:**

```
UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController 
                                 alertControllerWithTitle:@"Forgot Password" 
                                 message:@"" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

UIAlertAction* submit = [UIAlertAction 
                             actionWithTitle:@"Submit" 
                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                             handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                               //Do Some action here
                               UITextField *alertTextField = alert.textFields.firstObject;

                               NSLog(@"%d",[self validateEmailWithString:alertTextField.text]);
                               int returnValue = (int)[self validateEmailWithString:alertTextField.text];
                               NSLog(@"interger value %i",returnValue);
                               if ( returnValue == 1) {
                                   NSLog(@"correct format");
                               }else
                                 NSLog(@"wrong format");

                        }];
UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction 
                             actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" 
                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                             handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                                [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                        }];

[alert addAction:submit];
[alert addAction:cancel];

[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
    textField.placeholder = @"Enter your E-Mail Address";
    _enteredEMail = textField.text;
    NSLog(@"%@ntered Email Address",textField.text);
```

Comment: UIAlertController does not support an error message in red at the bottom of the text field but you can change colour of text field.

Comment: okay , that's good but how do i hold the dialog box(alert)  untill the right input is received in the text field?

Comment: You can call UIAlertAction on submit button action or more simple you can validate text and enable submit button.

Answer (score 0):

UIAlertController does not support an error message in red at the bottom of the text field but you can change colour of text field.

Add this method to check length of textField.text or you can add email validation check and then enable submit button.

```
submit.enabled = NO; //after submit button UIAlertAction set 

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
        {
             NSString *finalString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
             [submit setEnabled:(finalString.length >= 1)];
             // for textField border colour 
             textField.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
             textField.layer.borderWidth= 2.0f;
             return YES;
        }
```

You can't hold the dialog box but to can call it again from submit button action if returnValue == 0.

```
if ( returnValue == 0) {
    NSLog(@"correct format");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"wrong format");
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Also refer [UIAlertView Text Input and Validation](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-5-sdk-uialertview-text-input-and-validation--mobile-8388).

Comment: if ( returnValue == 1) {
                                                       NSLog(@"correct format");
                                                       [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                                      }
                                                   else
                                                       NSLog(@"wrong format");
                                                   [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
alert in a loop now, if and else in both cases it is appearing.

Comment: Yes. It will in loop but after submit button click it will automatically

Comment: On submit button click it will automatically dismiss current alert view only if email in wrong format then only alert view call itself. Its does not create stack of alert views.

Comment: Why don't you try custom deck card view to enter password its easy to validate and dismiss.